# Employer asking for lengthy handover which was already done

Tags: resignation

I worked at Old Company(name made up; 3 people from different fields) where they take projects from third party companies to develop products.  I was the most senior employee in my field and I had to perform substantial research, both using the internet and my contacts, in order to get my job done.

I found a new job with New Employer, gave my notice to Old Company and served my notice period which included a handover, and joined New Employer.

Old Company says the handover isn't finished yet. Both Old Company and one of their clients are now asking me to verify that some tests generated by the client pass, and provide video evidence.

The client has been using my personal contact number to make this request.

I asked the client to contact Old Company but they still keep on contacting me.

I work in an Asian country and fear disclosing country name here.

Am I supposed to do that work?

Is there something I can do to make them clear I did my part and it's not my job now?

Comment: Hi Titla - It's a good question, but you need to clean it up a little. Are you saying that a connection recommended you for a different company? Do you work there (new company) now - i.e. you have already left? Are you still at old company, but within the notice period? _I am currently doing well in this company_ implies that you left 2 months ago.

Comment: When you refer to "employer is asking me to do the same", is this your old employer or your new one? Also, how are clients keeping in touch with you? Are they using your personal contact information? Do they know you don't work at that company anymore?

Comment: What the others said - and also could you add your country?

Comment: If the summary in Matthew's answer below is accurate, you should [edit] this to strip some of the unnecessary / confusing details. I also recommend you take a look at [this off-site post](https://www.askamanager.org/2011/02/answering-questions-from-your-old-employer-after-youve-moved-on.html).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Justin Erik Daniel & Lilienthal. I have modified my question.

Comment: Titla, keep in mind that to answer what someone/some company can do legally we need a country tag, as laws are country-specific. In some cases we might even need more clarification (e.g. State in the US)

Comment: I removed the question about disparagement.  Of course anyone can say anything they want, but you seem to be asking a legal question there, which probably belongs at https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Specifically if your country is India, the whole matter of challenging if conditions were met to be issued a relieving letter and how you can challenge that will require people with country specific knowledge.  The whole premise of employment relieving is absent from the experience of most users to this site.

Comment: If you for some reason decide to do that work for the previous employer (free or for pay), you should let your current employer know and ask if they might consider that as an inappropriate conflict of interest. If they do, they might want their attorneys to take over your negotiations with your previous employer.

Answer (score 59):

It's a bit unclear from your question but I am assuming that:

1. Your connection recommended you for a new company.
2. You applied and were successful.
3. You served notice and worked you notice period
   before starting employment with the new company.

If this is all true then you do not need to complete the tasks that your previous employer is asking you to. You did everything right and their lack of planning is not your problem to solve. There is very little your previous employer can do in this situation, they could withhold a good reference in the future but this shouldn't be a problem if your work with your new employer is acceptable.

One option if you have a good relationship with your previous employer is to negotiate a price for completing the tasks (if your current contract allows you to undertake additional work). However don't feel like you have to do this.

To answer the last part you could reply along the lines of

"Thank you for getting in touch. As you know my employment with you ceased 2 months ago so I am unable to carry out the tasks you outlined. My handover notes contain all the information you need to complete them."

---

OP mentioned it is the client of their previous employer contacting them. In this case I would mention once more that you are no longer employed by the company and that they need to contact your old employer to resolve any outstanding issues. After this I would block their number from my mobile phone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106816/discussion-on-answer-by-matthew-salt-employer-asking-for-lengthy-handover-which).

Comment: *"After this I would block their number from my mobile phone."* ... and, in the future, **never again give out your private phone number to clients**.

Comment: @Heinzi That goes both ways; it could be how OP found the new job.

Answer (score 11):

### This is the perfect situation for a *yes, and...* rather than a *no*

> *As I'm no longer in contract with Old Company, we'll need to agree a new contract to do the additional work you've requested. My rate is **X**.*

This reframes the discussion: they understand now that you're not naive enough to be pressured/guilted into doing free work, and that the only way forwards is a yes to a contract at **X**.

If you want them to stop contacting you, make **X** too large.

If you'd actually quite like the extra work, make **X**... just large.

Comment: Potentially, but it depends on the new employer, contract and company culture, whether this is permissible, or violates contract or non-compete.

Comment: @smci Plus, someone who has been a full time employee with no contracting experience might not want to get into contracting, or not in this manner. It's not worth the extra tax complications and whatnot.

Comment: @Kaz: we can't say one way or the other, it depends on a ton of things: the non-compete situation, whether this arrangement would be considered ok, how close rivals the companies are, tax code, OP's level of experience etc.

Answer (score 10):

Without knowing the details of any contract you signed or the country you are in (and hence the relevant employment law) no-one can really give you a proper answer here. The laws and social conventions of your country will make a massive difference. If in doubt talk to a lawyer (although that's probably more drastic a step than you need take at this point).

What we can say is that in general after you finished your notice period and resolve everything to which you are contractually bound, your prior employer has no right to expect you to do further work and a professional employer would not even try - or if they did ask you to come back to finish something they would offer you a contract position to do so.

You also risk violating your contract with your new employer if you do anything for your past employer. This could ironically give your past employer leverage over you in a situation wher they currently have none!

Ethically and legally your past employer (probably) can't do anything about it. If they are vindictive and connected you do risk them trying something else such as contacting your current employer but there is little you can do about that beyond making sure your position is solid.

1. Document what happened including dates and emails so you have a written record while it's all fresh in your mind.
2. Send an email or other written notification to the client saying that you no longer work for X and unfortunately you are not able to work on their project. They should now contact Y@X.
3. Block the client's number.
4. Send an email or other written notification to your past employer saying that you no longer work for them and unfortunately you are not able to work on their project. Your handover notes can be found in X.
5. Block your past employer's number.
6. Optionally, notify your current boss that your previous employer has been asking you to come back because they are struggling to complete a project without you. Let your new boss know that you did a full handover before you left and will not be doing any side work or letting there be any distractions from your new role.

   - This step is optional because, depending on your relationship with your boss, it may or may not be helpful.
7. If they do contact your current employer just say something along the lines of: "I did hear they were struggling without me. They even tried to get me to come back but and do more work for them, but I'm very happy here. I did a thorough handover so I did what I could for them before I left."

Comment: Contacting New Employer is mandatory rather than optional, to preemp the situation that Old Employer is reaching out to New Employer and telling them whatever kind of... not-quite-truths. It also gives them the ability to plan: Negotiate a contract with Old Employer, tell Employee what to do (which eliminates risk of contract violation by Employee), have a better idea how Old Employer acts. The only reason not to contact New Employer would be if New Employer might act unreasonably.

Comment: @toolforger "reason not to contact" is not compatible with "mandatory". We've no idea how the new employer may or may not react - the OP is in a much better position to judge that.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's unwise to do something even if it's mandatory. "Mandatory" is always a question who mandates that you do it, so the term is much more subjective than people tend to assume.

Answer (score 1):

While I like the answer suggesting you offer your rates; in some countries side business is frowned upon. You can also talk to your current boss about it (or ask your old boss if it is ok to ask your current boss). Then your current company can send a quotation for their service (which then you can fufill). That would basically be a win-win-win situation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is the employers responsibility to ensure that his business can function. That includes any documentation and handover work that needs to be done by an employee who is leaving.

Another general principle is "no work without pay". You are not employed there anymore, so you have no duty to complete any work for them. You may have other duties, such as returning any of their property if you haven't already, but your duty to do the work you got paid for ended when the employment ended.

All that said, there may of course be more specific conditions in your contract or in the law of your country. Note that most conditions of the contract will also end with the contract, and even though employers love to write things into there that continue after employment, those aren't always legally enforceable.

If you have legal insurance or are organized in a union, you should have the option to get a free lawyer consultation and should use that.

Once you are clear that you have no legal duties to them, you should state to those who contact you clearly "please do not contact me anymore regarding this matter". In many countries it is actually illegal for a business to contact you after you explicitly told them not to. While these laws are often written with advertisement or phone sales in mind, they're often broad enough to cover this situation. Again, a lawyer can advise you.

I think that's all you can get from the Internet without being more specific about your country and other details.

Answer (score 1):

Once the contract term has ended, you are not required to continue working for them, since contract is contract - and the end date upon termination (whether mutually agreed upon or not) is final and legally binding. If your previous employer thinks otherwise, they might have issues because they have nobody able to replace you in a meaningful way; their request is anything but serious, because they ignore the termination of the contract. Also, you are certainly not obliged to provide them with any of your contacts; either they have them on file or they just don't have them.

So, if they need further work to be performed or have more than just minor questions to ask, it might be an option to you speak with your new employer, if performing some side-work would be acceptable under the new contract terms, which you have now (some contracts may explicitly outlaw this) and then ask your previous employer if they would be whiling to pay for the work to be performed (you need a new contract with them, explicitly stating the conditions). Either they agree to pay you - but if they think they would be entitled to, it is probably their problem and not your's.

They'd have no chance at the court; it's rather some kind of harassment, if they give your private contact information to one of their clients (and if you tell them to never call you again, you could then report them to the police, when they do not cease to bother you, because this equals stalking - especially when you never gave them your number). They are only permitted to call to the number of a SIM chip registered to your previous employer. This all might vary from country to country; but in a general sense, it should be quite a similar legal situation everywhere.

The most easy solution might be, to refer them someone able to replace you; in case you know someone. Because if you explain it to someone unable to do the job, this might be a waste of time and nerves and in the end, they likely still not have a suitable replacement. Admittedly, I read this between the lines, when they claim that the handover would not have been completed - simply because they had all the time to do so, since you adhered to your legal requirements, based upon the contract terms. If you wish to stay perfectly upright, the best solution might be to offer them to perform the hand-over in a meaningful way, once they've managed to find a suitable replacement for you. But since they've already made questionable claims, a written contract for the coaching to be performed should be made; the previous work contract cannot be the base for this, because it is already voided since the date of termination; it's irrelevant what you may have done or not done.